# Python print format

Tags: python

I start with a list tbe_fmt. having trouble formatting the write to file.
Trouble in left justify.  Perhaps better way.

```py
tbe_fmt = []
for i,j,k in zip(idx_tbe, inn_dia, out_dia):
    tbe_fmt.append(str(inn_dia[i])+' x '+str(out_dia[i]))

>>> tbe_fmt  = ['1.63 x 1.91', '2.09 x 2.38', 
>>>             '2.50 x 2.88', '3.10 x 3.50', 
>>>             '4.06 x 4.50']

tbe_str = ''
for i in tbe_fmt:
    tbe_str += i+','+' '
tbe_str = tbe_str.strip()
tbe_str = tbe_str[:-1]
tbe_str = '['+tbe_str+']'

ins_tbe_fmt = 'ins_tbe_fmt = '
tbe_str = tbe_str.replace(',', ','+'\\'+'\n')
tbe_str = tbe_str.ljust(len(ins_tbe_fmt))

desired output is:
ins_tbe_fmt = [1.63 x 1.91,\
               2.09 x 2.38,\
               2.50 x 2.88,\
               3.10 x 3.50,\
               4.06 x 4.50]
```

Comment: "Trouble in left justify" - could you explain what you mean with this?

Comment: Hi. sorry for sketchy explanation.  before i do poor explaining once more. desired when i write to file would be where ins_tbe_fmt captioned. I'll try once more left justify. i cant get to print as shown (justify from left).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
letters = list("abcdefgh")
out = "letters = [" + letters[0] + ",\\"
for let in letters[1:-1]:
    out = out + "\n\t" + let + ",\\"

out = out + "\n\t" + letters[-1] + "]"
```

outputs:

```
letters = [a,\
        b,\
        c,\
        d,\
        e,\
        f,\
        g,\
        h]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
idx_tbe = [0, 1, 2, 3, 9]
inn_dia = ['1.63', '2.09', '2.50', '3.10', '', '', '', '', '', '4.06']
out_dia = ['1.91', '2.38', '2.88', '3.50', '', '', '', '', '', '4.50']

get_tbe = []
for i,j,k in zip(idx_tbe, inn_dia, out_dia):
    get_tbe.append(str(inn_dia[i])+' x '+str(out_dia[i]))

ins_tbe_ttk = 'ins_tbe_fmt = ['
print (ins_tbe_ttk, end = '')

q = 1
nul = len(get_tbe)
ttk = len(ins_tbe_ttk)

for i in get_tbe:
    j = i
    if q == 1:
        q = 0        
        get = ('\'') + str((f'{str(j):>{nul}}' + ('\'')))
        print (get)
    else:
        if q < len(get_tbe):
            hok = ' ' * ttk
            get = hok + ('\'') + str((f'{str(j):>{nul}}' + ('\'')))
            print (get)
            q += 1
        else:
            get = hok + ('\'') + str((f'{str(j):>{nul}}' + (']')))
            print (get)
        q += 1
```

; for list ; str for another ; @David cheers bro ; will do have a look 
; this thing kicked my ass

Comment: Okay, best of luck to you!